# Store OAuth access token in rails backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0

I have a rails backend that is using OAuth to connect to a service that allows me to send sms messages. I have build out all of the functionality I need between the my backend and the service however I do not have a way to store the access token long term. Because of this I have been signing in and receiving a token before each request I make to the service (I know this is a bad practice). Is there a secure way I could store the token long term so that I can avoid signing in each time I need to make a request. I was under the impression that a database is not a secure solution to this problem.

Comment: I always store them in the DB.  Depends what the token is giving access to and what you're worried about happening.

http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72475/should-we-store-accesstoken-in-our-database-for-oauth2

Comment: Cool thanks. This clears things up for me a bit. I guess I will store it in the database.